# Django Foreign Key to_field

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have 2 models **CustomUser** and **Magazine** with random/unique slug fields. Now I want to create a third model (Article) with foreign keys to the slug field:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    slug = RandomSlugField(length=6, unique=True)
    ...

class Magazine(models.Model):
    slug = RandomSlugField(length=6, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField()

class Article(models.Model):
    magazine = models.ForeignKey(Magazine, to_field='slug')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, to_field='slug')
```

But when I migrate the database to create the Article model, I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: CustomUser has no field named 'slug'
```

But CustomUser obviously has a field named 'slug'.

And for the Magazine model I don't get this error. 
Has anyone an idea what is going wrong?

I use this package for the slug field:
https://github.com/mkrjhnsn/django-randomslugfield

EDIT:
Here is the full CustomUser model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    slug = RandomSlugField(length=6, exclude_upper=True)
    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'), max_length=30,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer.'
                'Letters, digits and '
                '@/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                                  _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
        ])
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)

    # email is our unique field for authentication
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log '
                    'into this admin site.')
        )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.')
        )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    profile = models.OneToOneField('UserProfile', blank=True, null=True,
                               related_name='user_profile')

    image = models.ImageField(default='images/noimage.jpg',
                          upload_to=settings.PROFILE_IMAGE_PATH,
                          max_length=255)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

Comment: obvious question - I assume `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is pointing to `CustomUser`?

Comment: yes it is :) I have `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_auth.CustomUser'` in my settings file.

Comment: had you previously done the necessary migration to add `slug` field to `CustomUser` model? ...it may be that inside the migration the user model is still in it's old state

Comment: Yes, the `slug` field of `CustomUser` model is already in the database. And I am using it already for querying

Comment: Try to use `get_usel_model` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model

Comment: @EdwinLunando that is not working, because the models aren't loaded yet. The problem is not the Foreignkey to the Usermodel, but the `to_field`

Comment: I take it you're using the RandomSlugField package. Question; what is the difference between ŔandomSlugField and RandomSlugField? Does the accent matter in some way?

Comment: @FlipperPA, that was just a typo.

Comment: Ah, I figured; I've never try to use to_field with AbstractBaseUser (or AbstractUser). Can you include your entire CustomUser model, including settings like USERNAME_FIELD?

Comment: @FlipperPA I just added it

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm stuck with the same problem...

Comment: No, I couldn't find a solution. In the end I didn't use `to_field`

Answer (score 2):

delete the database, all migrations except **init** and try it

Comment: Just delete whole migrations folder